# How to normalise data between [-1, 1] in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, normalization

I was wondering if there is a built in normalisation function in flutter. That works like this

```
List<int> array = [-105,24,66,-50,-49,2]

//Normalises to get numbers between -1 and 1
List<double> normalised = array.normalise(-1,1)
```

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by "normalisation"?  What are the values you want to get?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm afraid there isn't one, but I've made what you're looking for manually:

```
import 'dart:math';

List<int> array = [-105, 24, 66, -50, -49, 2];
final lower = array.reduce(min);
final upper = array.reduce(max);
final List<double> normalized = [];

array.forEach((element) => element < 0
    ? normalized.add(-(element / lower))
    : normalized.add(element / upper));

print(normalized);
```

Comment: The `num.parse(...).toStringAsFixed(2)` and sorting parts are extraneous.  Also, it's unclear exactly what form of "normalization" is desired, but scaling negative values independently of positive values seems a bit strange to me.

Comment: This was just a quick answer for [-1,1] normalization, as it will always end up multiplying by 1, it is implicitly in the `(element/lower) * 1)`. And yes, I agree that there's more than needs to be done, it was just to round at .2 places. I'll edit my answer.